# How to get ggplot2 geom_contour to replicate base graphics contour

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, contour

I am using a copula to look at the probability of occurrence of events based on duration and magnitude of the events. I can create contours for recurrence intervals with observed and simulated data in base R graphics, but I can't figure out how to reproduce in ggplot2. Why not just produce the graphs in base graphics and move on you may be wondering? Because I'm including the graphs in a short summary report and want to have consistency with numerous other graphs in the report. Below is some example code. I know that  using the location, scale, and shape for the GEV distribution to create random deviates to get the same distribution from is not ideal, but it is the best way I could think of to create a somewhat reproducible example, despite the poor correlation at the end. In base R, the contours are generated from a matrix of simulated data. Is this possible in ggplot2?

```
library(evd)
library(copula)

dur <- rgev(500, 2.854659, 2.170122, -0.007829)

mag <- rgev(500, 0.02482, 0.01996, 0.04603)

fDurGev <- fgev(dur)

fMagGev <- fgev(mag)

durVec <- dgev(dur, fDurGev[[1]][1], fDurGev[[1]][2], fDurGev[[1]][3])

magVec <- dgev(mag, fMagGev[[1]][1], fMagGev[[1]][2], fMagGev[[1]][3])

durMagMat <- as.matrix(cbind(duration = durVec, magnitude = magVec))

theta <- coef(fitCopula(claytonCopula(dim = 2), durMagMat, method = "itau"))

clayCop <- claytonCopula(theta, dim = 2)

fCopDurMag <- pCopula(durMagMat, clayCop)

copPts <- data.frame(duration = dur, magnitude = mag, copNEP = fCopDurMag, 
                     copEP = (1 - fCopDurMag), copRI = (1 / fCopDurMag))

fSim <- seq(0.05, 0.99998, length.out = 1000)

quaDur <- qgev(fSim, fDurGev[[1]][1], fDurGev[[1]][2], fDurGev[[1]][3])

quaMag <- qgev(fSim, fMagGev[[1]][1], fMagGev[[1]][2], fMagGev[[1]][3])

expDurMagMat <- cbind(expand.grid(fSim, fSim)$Var1, expand.grid(fSim, 
                                                        fSim)$Var2)

simPred <- pCopula(expDurMagMat, clayCop)

simPredMat <- matrix(simPred, 1000, 1000)

simDF <- data.frame(simDur = quaDur, simMag = quaMag, simPredMat)

rndPred <- data.frame(rCopula(5000, clayCop))

rndPred$rndDur <- qgev(rndPred[,1], fDurGev[[1]][1], fDurGev[[1]][2], 
                       fDurGev[[1]][3])

rndPred$rndMag <- qgev(rndPred[,2], fMagGev[[1]][1], fMagGev[[1]][2], 
                       fMagGev[[1]][3])

RI <- c(1.25, 2 ,5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500)
NEP <- 1 - (1 / RI)

plot(rndPred$rndDur, rndPred$rndMag, col = "light grey", cex = 0.5, xlab = 
     "Duration (time)", ylab = "Magnitude (x)")

points(copPts[,1], copPts[,2], col = "red", cex = 0.5)

contour(simDF$simDur, simDF$simMag, simPredMat, levels = NEP, labels = RI,  
        xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i', labcex = 0.6, lwd = 1, col = "black", add = 
        TRUE, method = "flattest", vfont = c("sans serif", "plain"))
```

[image: contour plot from base graphics]

And now for my attempt to recreate in ggplot2 (which fails to draw contours).

```
library(dplyr)

simDF <- data.frame(dur = expDurMagMat[, 1], mag = expDurMagMat[, 2], NEP = simPred)

simDF <- simDF %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(quaDur = qgev(NEP, fDurGev[[1]][1], fDurGev[[1]][2], fDurGev[[1]][3])) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(quaMag = qgev(NEP, fMagGev[[1]][1], fMagGev[[1]][2], fMagGev[[1]][3]))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = rndPred, aes(x = rndDur, y = rndMag)) +
  geom_point(color = "light grey", alpha = 0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Duration (time)", y = "Magnitude (x)") +
  geom_point(data = copPts, aes(x = duration, y = magnitude), 
             color = "red") +
  geom_contour(data = simDF, aes(x = quaDur, y = quaMag, z = NEP), 
               inherit.aes = FALSE, breaks = NEP) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: plot from ggplot2 which fails on contours]

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: The question is not reproducible in the current state (`simPred` is missing), any chance you can make it simpler?

Comment: Indeed, please remove the data preparation step and dependencies to other package (which seem irrelevant to the actual - and interesting - plotting question). Just post a _minimal_ data set, ready to use, and the relevant plot code.

Comment: @GGamba, `simPred` is in there. You may need to scroll down in the code block on the top. @Henrik, the data set produced has to be fairly large in order to replicate the error and etc. Without the code creating the non-exceedance probabilities and etc, I'm not sure how I would get the matrix to line up with the actual (simulated) data. I thought about that for a while and couldn't get it right without going through the whole process.